# The command puppet cert list is giving an error

Tags: puppet, cert

When I type the command puppert cert list it gives me the following error:
Error: Unknown Puppet subcommand 'cert'
See 'puppet help' for help on available puppet subcommands

I'm using puppet version 7.23.0 on centos stream 8[puppet cert list output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EajT8.png)

Comment: The `puppet cert` command is long obsolete.  It no longer exists in Puppet 7.  You're probably looking for `puppetserver ca`, instead.  Read its docs, as the details may differ a bit from the old `puppet cert`.